# Best use of Optionals in RestAPI Spring application

Tags: java, spring, rest, option-type

I am kind of confused about the way I should design repository -> service -> controller communication using Optionals in my RestAPI Spring app.
For instance, client wants to find film by id, but film is not present and repository returns empty Optional. I have two ways of dealing with it:

1. Service method returns Optional value or throws Exception which can be handled in Controller using ControllerAdvice.
2. Service returns Optional and Controller deals with it (return value if present or handle exception, or maybe just do something else).

I know that using exceptions for such simple situations is not best practice, probably you may suggest other ways of letting client know that id is wrong.

Method in RestController currently:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public FilmGetDto getFilm(@PathVariable int id) {
    return filmService.getFilm(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most followed practice I have followed or seen people doing is you should handle it in service and use wrapper class for response. By this way you will achieve two things i.e. you will have a constant Response object that you can use in all of your application and also you can use exceptions etc very easily with that. You should always handle any sought of business logic in service layer as MVC states. I am posting an example here so that you can understand better what I am trying to say here.

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public Response getFilm(@PathVariable int id) {
    return filmService.getFilm(id);
}
```

Service:

```java
public Response getFilm(int id){
  Optional<Film> film = repo.findById(id);
  return film.map(f -> Response.builder().status(200).data(f).message("request  successful"))
             .orElseGet(() -> Response.builder().status(422).data(null).message("Film with given id not found");

}
```

and Response class with be like as suggested by @Adrash as well

```
class Response {
  private int status;
  private Object data;
  private String message;
   
  //you can use lombok or IDE  generate getter setters to generate getters setters
 }
```

**Note: I have used lombok builder method to create response object in service layer.**

Comment: Hello there again. How do you deal with HTTP codes using wrappers? Returning ResponseEntity with status code and data or?

Comment: Hi @Tovarisch, Sorry if i didn;t understoon your question but I think what you are trying to ask is how I use http code in my Response object.
So answer to that will be you can use the property "status" in reponse class as HTTP code. 
Ofcourse Response is your class and you can modify it the way you want it to be

Comment: And if you want to add complete ResponseEntity object rather than just the code you can also use that instead of "private int status". 
or What I think you want to do is 
instead of private int status you can use "private HttpStatus statusCode". 
Hope this helps

Comment: I think that returning Response object that is obviously HTTP-coupled is not the best practice. Services should be more reusable and technology agnostic

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a message to the client about the non-existence of such id, you have to handle such edge cases.
probably you can use Optional and handle if optional.isPresent() returns false, you can send a customized message and let your client know that no data exist with such id.

You can use a wrapper class to achieve this.

```
class ErrorResponse {
  private String status;
  private int statusCode;
  private String message;

  public ErrorResponse(String status, int statusCode, String message){
      this.status = status;
      -----
      -----
   }
}
```

Set this feilds and return this class object as a response.

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow the standards, so you should not write the code in controller, instead you should write the code in services and also, you can wrap your response in a class provide it a appropriate custom message so that it makes sense to the client. as @Adarsh mentioned above the Wrapper class you can create exactly same and it would solve your problem. and follow the standards as mentioned by @Danish.